# Append or remove div using <input type='number'>

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to append or remove divs using `<input type='number'>`?
ex:

```
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" id='number' name='numberInput'>
```

```js
$("#number").on('change', function () {
    if (this.value > Previous number) {
        //append 'div'
    } else {
        //remove 'Previous div'
    }
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: Add/remove to/from what? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think you can expect to be down-voted because your question doesn't ask about any specific problem your facing and it isn't obvious that you have even tried anything. As a new user you can have a look at the help pages (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see how to write better questions and then you will find SO a very useful platform for answering specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var previousNumber=$("#number").val();

$("#number").on('change', function () {
    if (Number($(this).val()) > previousNumber) {
       $("#container").append("<div></div>");
    } else {
        $("#container").find("div").last().remove();
    }
    previousNumber = $(this).val();
});
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/29u92wos/2/

Comment: `1` is a magic constant, you know... I suppose, it will be better to use `var previousNumber = $("#number").val();`

Comment: And just one more thing: don't forget to mention, that whole this code is inside `$(window).load` (or `$(document).ready`).

Answer (score -1):

When the document is completely loaded, simply add a JavaScript variable called `num` and add the current value to it. On change, compare it to the previous declared `num`, and then update the `num` variable with the new value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = $('#number').val();
    $("#number").on('change', function () {
        if ( $(this).val() > num ) {
            //append 'div'
        } else {
            //remove 'Previous div'
        }
        num = $(this).val();
    });
});
```